# Taskkill not producing results

Tags: windows, command-line

After killing a process with taskkill "successfully":

```
SUCCESS: The process "problematic.exe" with PID 6896 has been terminated.
```

it still shows up in the tasklist with the same PID. What could be the reason / how to make the kill a success?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `/f` switch to force the process to be killed.

If it still doesn't kill it then it could be it has threads still running which would cause it to show up in tasklist.

Comment: @ Thanks, tried it... still no success, is there a way to kill the threads?

Comment: I don't think you can, that would be down to the application to tidy them up, which it probably won't if it's killed like that, which might explain why it doesn't end it. Maybe it's linked to a service that keeps it alive?

Comment: @ Could be, yes, I guess I have to boot then. Thanks.